# sending formatted email using AWS

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I am integrating AWS with my php website. I know how to send a simple text email to user.
But I want to send something formatted and images in that like this.

[image]

How can i send something like this using AWS(Amazon Web Service) ?
Is there documentation available on how to send this kind of an email?

Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Guess your problem is not with AWS... you need to build your email with HTML and CSS (use table instead of div) and send it using php mail function or something more powerful like phpmailer or swiftmailer

Comment: i was able to send it using AWS, but format which i am able to see in local is being changed in an email.

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952620/css-not-working-in-email-sending-using-aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using tables.

We can not use internal or external CSS in email. We can use the inline CSS. But in html email it's best to use tables.