# css not working in email sending using AWS

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, html-email

I am developing a website in php and want to send email to a user when user signs up.

I am able to do it successfully. 
Even i using html format and it's sending in html format.

I tried this. I know images should be uploaded to server but i will do it later.

```
$bodyPart = '
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">

<img id="header" style="position:absolute; left:85px; top:50px; " src="images/logo.jpg" width="140" height="90" border="0" alt="" /></a>


<img id="cloths" style="position:absolute; left:275px; top:25px;" src="images/cloths.jpg" width="350" height="300" border="0" alt="" /></a>

<font size="7" style="font-family:Times new Roman; position:absolute; left:50px; top:120px;">Thank YOU</font>

<font size="3" style="font-family:Times new Roman;position:absolute;left:50px; top:165px;">For registering with our team </font>

<img id="bag" style ="position:absolute; left:290px; top:345px;"src="images/bag1.jpg" width="250" height="240" border="0" alt="" /></a>

<img style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:440px; "id="watch" src="images/watch1.jpg" width="260" height="180" border="0" alt="" /></a>

</body>

';

  $m->setMessageFromString($plainTextBody,$bodyPart);

  print_r($ses->sendEmail($m));
```

I should be getting this output

[image]

But i am getting this instead.

[image]

But the problem is formatting is not properly done even if it works in my localhost as a independent file. I tried to use External CSS, Internal CSS and inline CSS. But it's not working.

Any example of CSS working with html in sending email would be very helpful.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: we don't know what setMessageFromString() and sendEmail() doing...

Comment: setMessageFromString is used to set email body part, where sendEmail is used to send an email after setting up message,sendTo,from and subject part.

Comment: your css is working and if you are expecting your images use the full path of image in src of image.

Comment: i know that i need to specify full path of image, as i already said in my question. How can you say that my css is working?

Comment: i have tested on my server...see in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**
As i assumed, you have just done copy paste.Try following code. Learn HTML basic syntax.

> Don't forget to upvote & mark as answered ;)

```
$bodyPart = ' 

<BODY 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
</head> 

<body style="margin-top:20px;"> 
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"> 


<tr> 
  <td> 
    <img id="header" src="images/logo.jpg" width="140" height="90" border="0" alt="" /></a> 
  </td>
  <td>
    <img id="cloths" src="images/cloths.jpg" width="350" height="300" border="0" alt="" /></a> 
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <font size="7" style="font-family:Times new Roman;">Thank YOU</font> 
  </td>
  <td>
    <font size="3" style="font-family:Times new Roman;">For registering with our team </font> 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <img id="bag" src="images/bag1.jpg" width="250" height="240" border="0" alt="" /></a> 
  </td>
  <td>
    <img id="watch" src="images/watch1.jpg" width="260" height="180" border="0" alt="" /></a> 
  </td>
  </tr> 
</table>';

echo $bodyPart;
```

**OLDER**
Make it simple. Put one table in your html body & fixed the width.

Your email body should be like following

```
$body = <<<BODY
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td>=============Your content =========</td>
</tr>
</table>
BODY;

echo $body;
```

Comment: it changed output, but still not getting proper formatting as it should be based on the CSS.

Comment: Note that any email client will not process external css/js .

You have to set css inline only.

Just create output using simple table. It works for everybody.

Might be some issue with your inline css

Comment: i m using inline css, and it works as independent file,but not while sending an email.

Comment: remove position absolute from your code & try ... i think its basic html alignment problem.

Comment: i already posted body code in my question. even i tried to remove position absolute but still no effect. :(

Comment: Did you tried my code ?? I think you are doing simply copy paste ....

don't just replace =============Your content ========= with your body code 

You have to format like below 

    <tr>

      <td><img id="header" style="width:140px;height:90px;" src="images/logo.jpg" /></a></td>


      <td><img id="cloths" style="width:350px;height:300px;" src="images/cloths.jpg" /></a></td>


    </tr>

Comment: Can you paste your code again with the example code i had given ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37868/discussion-between-mayur-kataria-and-bsthakrar)

Comment: hey, i meant why you are not using simple table in your email body & format your code. Paste your php code with html body here.I'll correct the same. Your problem is so simple .. but i don't know why you are making complex

Comment: @BSThakrar I think if you got the answer then select it as answered & close the thread

Comment: I am not getting proper output in email Thank You is displayed below center of the both the images, but it should be displayed direct below to the first image.

Answer (score 3):

My example here is using the [Boto3 library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) for [Python 3](https://www.python.org/) but I think it could still translate into this [PHP](http://www.php.net/) question mainly because the core of the problem is not [PHP](http://www.php.net/) specific but rather the [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) inside your `HTML_BODY` field for [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and that is language agnostic so my example here should help.

This code successfully sends to my email address, formatted exactly how it appears in [the example on W3 Schools here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_responsive)

**HTML Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Table</h2>
<p>A responsive table will display a horizontal scroll bar if the screen is too 
small to display the full content. Resize the browser window to see the effect:</p>
<p>To create a responsive table, add a container element (like div) with <strong>overflow-x:auto</strong> around the table element:</p>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**AWS SES Example Using The Above HTML:**

```
#Your Imports go here
import boto3

# Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
# This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
SENDER = "the_email_address_of_who_is_sending_this_email_out@gmail.com"

# Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
# is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
RECIPIENT = "the_email_address_of_who_will_be_receiving_this_email@gmail.com"

# Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
# set, comment the following variable, and the
# ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET argument below.
# CONFIGURATION_SET = "ConfigSet"

# If necessary, replace us-west-2 with the AWS Region you're using for Amazon SES.
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"

# The subject line for the email.
SUBJECT = "ARL Data Lake"

# The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
# BODY_TEXT = ("Amazon SES Test (Python)\r\n"
#             "This email was sent with Amazon SES using the "
#             "AWS SDK for Python (Boto)."
#             )
BODY_TEXT = str(records)

# The HTML body of the email.

BODY_HTML = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Responsive Table</h2>
    <p>A responsive table will display a horizontal scroll bar if the screen is too 
    small to display the full content. Resize the browser window to see the effect:</p>
    <p>To create a responsive table, add a container element (like div) with <strong>overflow-x:auto</strong> around the table element:</p>

    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
          <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Adam</td>
          <td>Johnson</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
          <td>67</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>"""

# The character encoding for the email.
CHARSET = "UTF-8"

# Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=AWS_REGION)

# Try to send the email.
try:
    # Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML,
                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT,
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER,
        # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
        # following line
        # ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET,
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong.
except Exception as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

**The Email Result:**

[image]

**Sources & Further Help/Examples:**

- Python to PHP: [Converting Python Code to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116596/converting-python-code-to-php)
- AWS Boto3 Python 3.6 SES Example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-python.html
- Basic HTML CSS For Tables: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp
- More AWS SES Help: https://aws.amazon.com/ses/getting-started/

**Note:**

To run this example easily I recommend setting up a quick [Cloud9 IDE in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/welcome.html), installing Python 3 on it, copy and paste my code into it, then click run. If your [Cloud9](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/welcome.html) has the proper roles and permissions to use SES then it should work. Also note that [Cloud9](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/welcome.html) is just running on top of an EC2-Instance so you can SSH into it (directly from the Management Console on your browser which is nice) and run something like "sudo yum install python-3.6" and manually run the code using "sudo touch code_example.py", "sudo chmod 755 code_example.py", "sudo vi code_example.py", then hit the "i" key which stands for insert, then right click and for my SSH client that pastes the code I had copied onto my clipboard into the SSH's text editor for VI, then click "ESC" to get out of insert mode, then click ":wq" and click enter which stands for "write" and then "quit", then to run it do "python3 code_example.py". If you successfully installed Python it should work. But like I said it's easier to just use Cloud9, open the IDE for Cloud9, create a new Python file, paste the code in, then run it as Python 3 there's a button that does it just like any normal IDE.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this helped me with my issue. i couldn't get the border working in SES but i followed your code and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Post your code..

But i think the Problem is your `Content-Type`.

Check this:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n
```

`text/html` is necessary..

**UPDATE:**

The path is not correct.

```
images/logo.jpg
```

Upload the image to the server (or imagehoster) and insert the whole link.

**UPDATE 2**

I think i have the solution:

The first parameter from `setMessageFromString()` is the plain Text. The second parameter requires the html content. If you want to sent HTML - Email, check this:

```
$m->setMessageFromString($plainTextBody, $HTMLBody);
```

Comment: it's a built-in function in SES(simple email service) provided by amazon.

Comment: i knw tht. But if tht the prblm only images should not be displayed why it changes formatting. see my question again for more details.

Comment: hmm.. maybe add `<html></html>` tag.

Comment: still the same. :(  thanks for your suggestions. let me know if you still have left any. :) I will try anything to get it working.

Comment: were you able to fix the formatting issue @keen

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$to = 'rajeevranjan@hostname.com'; 

$subject = 'Test email '; 
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: rajeev ranjan"; 
$message='<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">

<img id="header" style="position:absolute; left:85px; top:50px; " src="images/logo.jpg" width="140" height="90" border="0" alt="" /></a>


<img id="cloths" style="position:absolute; left:275px; top:25px;" src="images/cloths.jpg" width="350" height="300" border="0" alt="" /></a>

<font size="7" style="font-family:Times new Roman; position:absolute; left:50px; top:120px;">Thank YOU</font>

<font size="3" style="font-family:Times new Roman;position:absolute;left:50px; top:165px;">For registering with our team </font>

<img id="bag" style ="position:absolute; left:290px; top:345px;"src="images/bag1.jpg" width="250" height="240" border="0" alt="" /></a>

<img style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:440px; "id="watch" src="images/watch1.jpg" width="260" height="180" border="0" alt="" /></a>

</div>

';
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
?>
```

Comment: but my main problem is it doesn't work with Amazon service. i am not getting proper output. As you can see in my question. Any idea why?

Comment: I know about the images and i will upload it soon, but even CSS is not working.

Comment: I tried to use your script, just changed the to and from. And even in this i m not getting proper output. will you please post your received email screenshot ?

Comment: proper output relates to css i am not good in writing css.An HTML expert can do this for you.

Comment: bt you said that you are getting proper output in email

Comment: you viewed it as first screenshot i posted or the second one ?

Comment: can you please send mail on my id ? my id is thakrar_bhavesh@Yahoo.com .

Comment: i know i am also getting it this way. but it should display something like i posted the first screenshot in my question.